# Background Capablity on iOS

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications

What are the requirements and how would I go about implementing the Application Push Notification Service to trigger methods when the application is in the background, or when the phone is closed. Would this even be possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No thats not possible.

When the app is in the foreground it will receive the push notification directly and can do whatever it wants to in response to that.

However when its not in the foreground the notification is displayed to the user (if they haven't disabled them) and/or displayed in the notification center (if they haven't disabled that). Your app will be brought to the foreground to execute *if and only if* the user selects the notification.

The application does not receive the notification directly if its not in the foreground.

Answer (score 0):

Read the Apple Docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 0):

It boils down to lots of setup, and then implementing application:didReceiveRemoteNotification. You can read an in-depth example [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12). Part two goes into the actual application:didReceiveRemoteNotification implementation.

Comment: He wasn't asking how to implement push notifications, he was asking a specific question about background/closed situations.